# CPU load on Debian (webmin)

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

When I look at webmin's "system information" page it tells me that the CPU is much greater than when doing `top` in the terminal? Why? What is going on?

Today the server also broke down

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not to wonder what web-based tools show as a status. The information being shown there can be outdated (usually by a few seconds, often depends on how fast your browser loads the page).

Your screenshot of top seems to show a system which is mostly idling and not running any resource intensive processes.

I guess you screenshotted top before looking and your web tool?
Those web tools normally cause a high load when reading out the stats from your system, but that is  only temporary. The tools then show a higher load than there really is on the system since the web tools themselves cause this high load for a short amount of time.